# How to install mitmproxy on Android7

Tags: android, capture, mitmproxy

I installed mitmproxy on **centos7** to capture a network packet of an APP in **Android7.0**, and the result met my expectations.

But I want to install mitmproxy directly on Android7.0. In theory, I can directly capture data packets on the mobile side, and then send the data to the remote database through python.

In this way, I can save a centos device. In addition, my mitm proxy must support **TLS 1.3**, I tried many methods and tools, but none of them worked.

I want to know if there are suitable technical solutions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no TLS 3.0, only the very very old method SSLv3. Mitmproxy uses Python which uses OpenSSL and SSLv3 support was dropped long ago. Are you sure the uses protocol is SSLv3? For compatibility even long after SSLv3 was one the client handshake started with an SSLv3 HELLO but the agreed protocol was only TLSv1 and newer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your correction, I have made a modification, it should be 1.3

Comment: TLS 1.3 support should depend on the used OS/environment and the installed OpenSSL version. https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/4008#issuecomment-634589094